# Filtering with NSPredicate an Array of Array to see if It contains an Integer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

Hi I am trying to learn a bit more about NSPredicate- and its quite tough as the resources are still based on ObjC.  I would like a swift based answer if possible

Basically I am trying to use NSPredicate to see if the arrays below contain a "9" the code number for Male users. 
I thus want to filter the below `people` array and only keep arrays that contain the number 9.

```
var malePerson1:[Int] = [1,4,5,6,11,9]
var malePerson2:[Int] = [3,5,6,7,12,9]
var femalePerson3:[Int] = [3,5,6,7,12,10]

var people = [malePerson1, malePerson2, femalePerson3]
```

I have got the solution working fine using a filter (see below)

```
//Solution working with Filter
// male gender search
var result = people.filter{$0.contains(9)}
print(result)
var resultFemale = people.filter{$0.contains(10)}
print(resultFemale)
```

but how Do I do something similar using predicates?

Below doesn't work - resultMale just returns a blank array when it should contain the two arrays: `[maleperson1, maleperson2]`.  I think the problem is that its checking if 9 is contained in the 'people' array instead of checking the contents of the contained arrays.

Any ideas how to do what I am doing using NSPredicate to filter the integers in the array?

```
let malePred = NSPredicate(format: "9 IN %@",people) 
//9 is the code for Male user
var resultMale = (people as NSArray).filtered(using: malePred)
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate - the potential solutions are in objective C( and very old syntax) These solutions don't work on Swift

Comment: The predicate syntax is the same for Swift and Objective-C. For your case it is "ANY self == value", regardless which language you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ANY` to compare each nested array with `NSPredicate`.

```
let malePred = NSPredicate(format: "ANY self == 9")
```

Comment: Awesome @Nirav . - out of interest would it work if i want to filter on 9, 10 eg? ANY self == [9, 10]"

Comment: @MobileBloke Welcome mate :), You can use `IN` for that `let malePred = NSPredicate(format: "ANY self IN %@",[9, 10])`

Comment: Oops! - Done ! Thanks for the help.  Where do you learn all this about predicates? The Documentation seems quite weak.

Comment: @MobileBloke These two links helps you http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html